# How to authentificate with a Restful JSON API?

Tags: api, rest

Is there a possible answer about how to authentificate a user admin with a restful json API?

For example, is it a good practice, with a http get, to send username and password to the API?
And what the API should return ? (`apikey`?, `{success:true}`?)

Comment: If security is important to you, I would strongly suggest that you use an existing authentication library rather than writing your own. It's really hard to get it right, especially if you're not an expert in the field. You're much better off leveraging what somebody more knowledgeable has already written.

Comment: Oauth, stormpath. Do research.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are providing the API. So, based on this I suggest you the following terms:

For the user to authenticate to your API, create a singular API KEY for every of your users using it, and request it along user and passwd like this:

```
yourweb/api/auth/?user=xxxxxx&passwd=xxxxx&userkey=xxxxxx
```

Every step of the API should be done with HTTPs for security reasons.

As for the response, in your DB assign a auth_token for all your users, that is invalid after 6 hours, if not used or requested usage extension period.

```
{
    error: 0,
    auth_token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    expires_on: 134871324
}
```

Once user has auth_token, you can check it plus his userID to retrieve his ACL on the site. There is no need at all to tell in the API itself if its admin or not.

Comment: I don't get it, is it the same thing to connect to an admin part (for example) and to connect to a API ? I do not think so. A simple user will need to connect to my API for getting (GET Method) data and visualize throught the website.

Comment: You need to give authentication to every user, admin or not. What methods can each user access to depends on the ACL you give to each of them. You dont have to split your API into modules for this, only check the permissions from the user and the auth. But if you insist so much in creating a module apart for admins, then just add add /api/admin/auth/?...

Comment: Thks. Concerning the key, do you have any advice to store it in client side?

Comment: Well you can use itemStorage for this, but I'd recommend to make the developer save it in some kind of server-side variable or database because as we know, cookies and localStorage arent safe because anyone with enough knowledge can easily hack them. Another choice is to base64 the localStorage key and decypher it in code.

Comment: hmm, so how can I provide the key to the api if the user logs in for the first time, or from a new device ?

Comment: to access the API, the user has first to register on it. Then you give him his unique API KEY, which can use anytime, from anywhere (doesn't matter from where he logs in). Then once he has the auth_key, as long as the key isn't expired, it should work also from any device. If you yet want to have different keys for each of his devices, then you should check connection header for User-Agent and work around it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to authentication in a RESTful API is per request authentication and involves the client providing a credential (e.g. username/password) with each request.

Options for the authentication mechanism include HTTP Basic Authentication, query parameters, or parameters in the body as JSON/XML or form data.  Regardless of how the credentials are passed in, it should be over a secure channel (https).

It is very unlikely that an API needs to implement authentication/authorization itself as this is a mature space with many good implementations available off the shelf.

Most application containers/frameworks, include an implementation of HTTP Basic Authentication with the ability to authenticate clients and perform role based authorization against standard sources such as files, databases, LDAP servers, etc.  For credentials passed as body or URL parameters, a filter typically works well to parse the credentials and pass them on to the security provider.

In most application containers/frameworks, after performing authn/authz, the security provider augments the request with information information about the client including the id and roles.

Comment: Ok so on the one hand I need an aunthentification part provided by the chosen framework on the server side and on the other hand I need an API to provide/get data to/from database.
Furthermore, when a user has been authentificated, I give him an APIkey ?

Comment: When you say API key, I think of long term key used to give a client permission to access an API, without regard to the user "sitting at" the client. If the client is providing the credential with each request then that is all you need.

Comment: If the client will be making many requests and the authentication of the credential by the server is expensive, then you could use an auth_token.  You would implement a auth_token service that required authentication and returned an auth_token.  The key elements of the token are a user id, an expiration (typically measured in minutes), and a digital signature.  This could even be implemented as a cookie.  Then with each future API call, the token gets passed, validated by the server (good sig, not expired), then the server accepts the request as being from the user identified by the token.

Comment: Ok I am a little confused... Is it mandatory to have an secured API or not (maybe it depends on what you are storing ?)? In fact what I was wondering, if I do not create a authentification service via my API for a web app, in any cases I will have to make one for a mobile app. For a mobile app, I just get the credentials from a user, then I provide them to my API, it returns a success response or not finally I can store the result im my obj-c/java programm. But it sounds harder for a web app, for security reasons.